# Magento 1.9 :: Customer login or signup not working

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, customer-session, customer-login

I am using Magento 1.9.4.4 CE instance for my site and due to some reasons my website's login and registration forms has stopped working and I am unable to detect the issue.
Also, the session files are not created under the var/session directory.

I had tried the below solutions but still, the issue is the same for me.

(1) In the admin panel go to System -> Configuration -> Web-> Session Cookie Management

> Cookie Life Time: 3600

> Cookie Path: /

> Cookie Domain: .mydomain.com (The dot prefix is important)

> Use HTTP Only: No

> Cookie Restriction Mode: No

(2) Also I had changed the code and added the form key in both the login and signup forms using the below code.

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

But still, I am unable to create a new customer account after submitting the signup form. and also unable to login.

Also now I am unable to login into the Magento admin panel after using the above methods.

Comment: Could be related to this https://github.com/vianetz/secure-cookies-magento1 check you have blocked cookies, or try this and make sure it's not your browser https://github.com/vianetz/secure-cookies-magento1

Comment: Thanks @FROSIT for your help. I will check for it.